# Get new points after rotating android canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, rotation, android-canvas

I have an image that I draw using canvas.draw bitmap.  I need to rotate the image.  If I use

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(theta, centerX, centerY);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, null, new Rect(x1, y1, x3, y3), paint);
canvas.restore();
```

it works perfect, however I don't have the new rotated values of x1, y1, x3, y3, which I need. Is there any way to get them?  Or alternatively, is there another way to do this?

Thanks